# Render hyperlink button through gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a `hyperlink button` in `gridview` with the attribute `navigateurl = ""`.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="btntest" runat="server" CommandName="Print" 
     CommandArgument='<%# Eval("rentalid") %>'   NavigateUrl="" CssClass ="ImClass orangeButton" 
     Text="Display/Print Rental Agreement As PDF111" Target="_blank">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

I have a `gridview command` that makes a file and give this `hyperlink button` `navigateurl` attribute value but the problem is the `hyperlink button` is not calling `gridview command` because `navigateurl` is blank and also how can I render the `hyperlink button` when it got the `navigateurl` at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Use link button instead and do whatever stuff you want to do in command event of a linkbutton.
you can also style a linkbutton like a button.

Comment: I did used link button. The problem is when the file is made then I used Response.Redirect("abc.aspx") to go to the file but I wanted this to come it new tab/window. That's why I have used hyperlink button.
Is there any way I can render hyperlink button in the link button click event ?

Comment: the redirect link is same for all records ?

Comment: No, the file name changes every time.

Comment: depends on record binded on gridview?

Comment: No, I have used GUID that gives random file name.

Comment: can u plz gimme sample navigate url?

Comment: Sure, 
~/images/PDF FILES/03934f03-33cd-44df-82ba-371d18b55994.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.... there are a few ways we came up with, but the best option for us was to use a literal in our grid-view. We set the html in the literal to open in a new window and passed the query strings that we needed. We did this twice, once selecting out the HTML in a stored proc. The other on a Row Data Bound. It sounds like either could work in your situation.

Hope this helps!